# horizontal scrollbar which leaves extra white space on the right side of web page using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

There is a horizontal scrollbar appearing which is creating an extra space on the right side of the whole page while using bootstrap 3. please help me with this. How to avoid this?`

`

Comment: Please show an example of this supposedly faulty behaviour. And by example I mean more than just a screenshot, but rather a working example.

Comment: add *{display:none;} to your css
this will solve your problem

Comment: Are you speaking about hidding a scrollbar in a webpage how this would help you ..

`Set overflow: hidden;`

`<style type="text/css">
body {
    overflow:hidden;

}
</style>`